# Send PUT request with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have  to make service call with backbone to update user settings.  here is the simplified code:

```
var settingService = Backbone.Model.extend({
  "url": "usersettings"
});


var SettingsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.services = {
      "userSettingsService": new settingService()
    };
  },
  saveSettings: function() {
    this.services.userSettingsService.save({
      "currency": "USD",
      "dateFomat": "DD-MM-YYYY"
    })
  }
});

var settings_view = new SettingsView();

settings_view.saveSettings();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ovg3kyqz/2/

when I  call saveSettings the POST request is made which is not supported by backend. I need to make  PUT request. I know that Backbone decides whether model is  new based on its id and if so will send a PUT request

I can set

```
this.services.userSettingsService.set("id", 1)
```

and then on saveSettings a PUT request will be made but the request body will have {id: 1,...} which is not really what I want.

so how can I make a PUT request and not include id in the request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to overriding `isNew` (that I find more explicit) would be to override [model.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-sync):

```
var settingService = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: "usersettings",
  sync: function(method) {
    if (method === "create") {
      arguments[0] = "update";
    }
    return Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pytpfnar/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could simply override the [`isNew` method](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isNew) on your model to always return `false` and thus always send a `PUT` request. Something like

```
var settingService = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "usersettings",
    isNew: function () {
        return false;
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/ehhwqm70/